# How to edit header after importing it via PHP

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a header consisting a `fixed-top` navbar which comes from Bootstrap. As any sensible person would I put my header(and footer) in a separate HTML file and later I call it in whatever webpage I'm making using:

```
<?php include "./header.html" ?>
```

Now the problem is, on my home page, I want the navbar to be `fixed-top` but on my other pages I want it to be `static-top`. Is there any way I can modify navbar classes after importing it using a PHP `include` or do I just have to put a different header every time I want custom behaviour on a page?

Comment: Make it a PHP script file instead of a static HTML file. Then you can access all variables from the current scope of the main script in it, and modify the output based on them. So just set `$isHomePage = true;` or false before or something like that, and inside the include file echo the `fixed-top` or `static-top` class based on that …

Comment: ^-- This, or include dynamically some JS that modify on the fly the classes of the navbar

Comment: Sounds like you should start using proper templates instead of simple includes?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your file `header.html` to `header.php` file and do something like this:

```
$nav_fixed = '<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">'; // and other html
$nav_static ='<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">'; // and other html

if ( /* add your check here */) {
    echo $nav_fixed;
} else {
    echo $nav_static;
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a bit? Do the two navbar variables only get the first tag? And what is the condition that goes in the `if` statement?

Comment: In if statemt You need to put in your logic that specifies which header to display.